# Sort text file alphabetically in groups (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, file, sorting, grouping

I know how to sort a text file alphabetically but I'm trying to do more than sorting (i.e. grouping).

I'm trying to create a Unix Shell script that formats /etc/hosts file in my organization in the following format:

```
From: 
Xsb ip 
aabc ip 
A2bc ip 
Eexg ip 
exx ip 
Fxg ip


To:

### A 
aabc ip 
a2bc ip 
### E 
eexg ip 
exx ip
### F 
fxg ip
### X
xsb ip
```

Then I'll create another script to add new hostname lines but for now I'm not sure what's the most compact way to do this. I thought perhaps I'll need to loop on all initial letters of the hostnames with a for loop but your expert advice is highly appreciated on the shortest way.

Comment: While WangJie's answer does what you ask you might consider using bind if you find your **/etc/hosts** to be that complex .. :}

Comment: The problem with your question is that `/etc/hosts` has the entry format of `<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>` where the final `hostname` (or shortname) can be any number of aliases. Does your `/etc/host` contain more than one alias for any IP? If so, do you want a listing for each? How will comments in `/etc/hosts` be handled? What have you tried so far? Where is it failing?

Comment: Thank you David for your comment. I haven't started creating a script yet and I am still brainstorming. I'm working in a very huge environment where there are hundreds of host names in  tens of /etc/hosts and multiple users who edit the file so I wanted to created a process through a shell script that could unify /etc/hosts edit. The comments will be at the very top or very bottom of the /etc/hosts appending each time the script runs. I plan to use small containers for that purpose (i.e. header.in, comments.in, main.in) whereby each is appended and redirected into final /etc/hosts output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script maybe achieve your need.

```
tr A-Z a-z | sort | awk '{\
  if (last != substr($0, 0, 1)) {\
    print "### "toupper(substr($0,0,1))"\n"$0; last = substr($1, 0, 1)\
  } else {\
    print $0\
  }\
}'
```

- `tr` convert letters to lowercase
- `sort` sort text alphabetically
- `awk` add '###' when first letter of line different from next line

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank You very much WangJie, please give me some time to validate and then you'll have the best answer. Awesome :)